# How can I write a Perl script to submit a form that is inside another form on a JavaScript page

Tags: javascript, forms, perl

On a web server (not mine) with JavaScript pages (probably generated with a Java API) there is a page accessible with authentication. On this page there is a form that I can access with a Perl script and fill input fields, but the validation button of this form, when clicked, open a new window with two buttons. I want my script to click on (validate/cancel) in this new window but I don't know on to access the form. This page contains the HTML code below.

Could you give me hint to access the hidden form?

```
<div class="button_send_message">
<a class="button" href="#" id="_PRE__MAI:_viewRoot:mainInclude:web2SmsForm:web2SmsSendButton"
name="_PRE__MAI:_viewRoot:mainInclude:web2SmsForm:web2SmsSendButton"
onclick="A4J.AJAX.Submit('_PRE__MAI:_viewRoot:a4jRegion_MessagingPage','_PRE__MAI:_viewRoot:mainInclude:web2SmsForm',
event,{'similarityGroupingId':'_PRE__MAI:_viewRoot:mainInclude:web2SmsForm:web2SmsSendButton',
'parameters':{'org.ajax4jsf.portlet.NAMESPACE':'PRE__MAI','javax.faces.portletbridge.STATE_ID':'d3090bfc\x2D223e\x2D40d3\x2Daf74\x2D7a17042408e6:view:PRE__MAI','_PRE__MAI:_viewRoot:mainInclude:web2SmsForm:web2SmsSendButton':'_PRE__MAI:_viewRoot:mainInclude:web2SmsForm:web2SmsSendButton'}
 ,'namespace':'PRE__MAI','actionUrl':'/SlfcrMessagingPortlet/faces/pages/main.xhtml?javax.portlet.faces.DirectLink=true'} );
return false;" onmouseout="className='button'" onmouseover="className='button_hover'" title="Envoyer"></a></div>
```

Does someone knows how I can call a submit form on the window?

The original URL for the form is at `/portal/authsec/portal/Selfcare/Messaging`

Comment: What module have you used to write your Perl script so far?

Comment: hi borodin until now I am using `use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use URI::URL;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
use Getopt::Long;
`

Comment: Can you see the form you want to submit in the HTML that LWP returns? It's probably created by JavaScript, and the usual solution is to use `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` which drives a real Firefox browser.

Comment: i know about  `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` but I need this script on a console only machine.

Comment: I can not use mech-dump to see the form if it is what you mean.

Comment: I can provide the full page if it can give hint to someone.

Comment: There is also `WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS`, but I gave never used it.

Comment: Do you need the actual page? Can't you just take the target of the form that that additional step with the JS does manually, then hard-code your program to trigger the first page, then trigger the second target with the appropriate fields? If the target is not dynamic in a way that you need the JS that would be enough.

Comment: @simbabque : that is what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1):

I was able to finaly use a chrome extension "http Trace" that show me clearly what the POST was like, and then I put it on my perl script and it works.